# How to open select input mode on keyboard's event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I have a keyboard that works and I would to implement a method into "onLongPress(..)" to open a default android dialog to change input mode.

Maybe I have to launch an activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android Framework already provides this functionality. you can show inputmethodPicker dialog like this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showInputMethodPicker();
```